# Detect IE browser compatibility mode on with ELM

Tags: elm

I have an application running in Elm. 
I need to show some alert msg to users before app loads in "IE compatible" mode as intend not to support, specific to IE Compatibility mode only.

with JavaScript I can do

```
navigator.userAgent.indexOf('compatible') > -1 ? true : false
```

But Is there a way to do that in ELm it self, like first thing in `Main.init` ?

I have tried using Elm port but application itself fails before reaching to port that's why it essential to check browser compatibility even before any Elm code runs.

Thanks

Comment: You say that it would be ideal to check browser compatibility even before any Elm code runs. Why not then just do the check with JS in index.html before Elm app is attached to the web page?

Comment: Right , But I am looking to handle this from Elm itself .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way could be to use [flags](https://guide.elm-lang.org/interop/flags.html). Flags are values that can be passed into Elm when you first initialize the app from JavaScript:

```
  var app = Elm.Main.init({
    node: document.getElementById('myapp'),
    flags: {
      compatibilityMode: navigator.userAgent.indexOf('compatible') > -1
    }
  });
```

and on the Elm side is passed to the `init` function:

```
type alias Model = { compatibilityMode : Bool, ... }

type alias Flags = { compatibilityMode : Bool }

init : Flags -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
init flags =
  ( { compatibilityMode = flags.compatibilityMode, ... }
  , Cmd.none
  )

...

main : Program Int Model Msg
main =
  Browser.element
    { init = init
    , view = view
    , update = update
    , subscriptions = subscriptions
    }
```

Comment: Here's an example: https://ellie-app.com/96YzK2jHPYJa1 (that said, you'll need to download and compile it yourself to test in IE, because Ellie doesn't work in IE)